# React native 8badf00d after updating xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I recently ran into the error code 8badf00d from spotlight when running my react native app on a iPhone 11 emulator (xcode).

After trying to find a fix for a few days I'm completely stuck. I figured the code means the app takes too long time to load to iOS kills it. Reasonable explanation, except the code still appear if I remove all screens from my app except the index.
Some timesI'm able to run the app without any problem, but images load blanks. Not sure if this is related but it began at the same time.

The 8badf00d code began to appear right after xCode decided to update, this was also right after I had added react-native-gifted-chat to my code.

Anyone know why I get 8badf00d at all? or even after removing all screens?

Error:

```
Process:               Spotlight [33334]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications/Spotlight.app/Spotlight
Identifier:            Spotlight
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [33167]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [875]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-09-24 16:37:34.038 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G2021)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.6 (17P6610)
Anonymous UUID:        08D5D057-5CCB-7FEE-671B-B85AA14ABFA0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       38781CBD-8A86-4DE4-B8A6-2495FF402105

Time Awake Since Boot: 62000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       580 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/ilostmymedic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/19G2021/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0.18A372
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/libfaceCore.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x0000000118e7814a __mmap + 10
1   dyld                            0x0000000118e7677a mmap + 81
2   dyld_sim                        0x000000010950e4ff ImageLoaderMachO::mapSegments(int, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 505
3   dyld_sim                        0x000000010950f475 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 341
4   dyld_sim                        0x000000010950aced ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 143
5   dyld_sim                        0x00000001094fb6be dyld::loadPhase6(int, stat const&, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) + 793
6   dyld_sim                        0x0000000109500653 dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 1693
7   dyld_sim                        0x00000001094fff54 dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 185
8   dyld_sim                        0x00000001094ffccf dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 1434
9   dyld_sim                        0x00000001094ff446 dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 186
10  dyld_sim                        0x00000001094fb358 dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 186
11  dyld_sim                        0x00000001094fb036 dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&) + 185
12  dyld_sim                        0x0000000109500b88 dyld::libraryLocator(char const*, bool, char const*, ImageLoader::RPathChain const*, unsigned int&) + 55
13  dyld_sim                        0x000000010950714c ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 346
14  dyld_sim                        0x0000000109507424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
15  dyld_sim                        0x0000000109507424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
16  dyld_sim                        0x0000000109507424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
17  dyld_sim                        0x0000000109507424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
18  dyld_sim                        0x0000000109507424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
19  dyld_sim                        0x0000000109507424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
20  dyld_sim                        0x0000000109506158 ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 90
21  dyld_sim                        0x00000001094fd671 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, unsigned int) + 383
22  dyld_sim                        0x00000001094feadc dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 3803
23  dyld_sim                        0x00000001094f91c7 start_sim + 122
24  dyld                            0x0000000118e2a85c dyld::useSimulatorDyld(int, macho_header const*, char const*, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*, unsigned long*) + 2308
25  dyld                            0x0000000118e284f4 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 837
26  dyld                            0x0000000118e23227 dyldbootstrap::start(dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, int, char const**, dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, unsigned long*) + 453
27  dyld                            0x0000000118e23025 _dyld_start + 37

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000135d8f000  rbx: 0x0000000125538d10  rcx: 0x00007ffee670e4f8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000135d8f000  rsi: 0x0000000000a29000  rbp: 0x00007ffee670e520  rsp: 0x00007ffee670e4f8
   r8: 0x0000000000000003   r9: 0x0000000000001000  r10: 0x0000000000000012  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x0000000000000003  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000a29000  r15: 0x0000000000000012
  rip: 0x0000000118e7814a  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x0000000118e1f000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000c5
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x1094e3000 -        0x1094ebfff  com.apple.Spotlight (1.0 - 1) <61A80A73-62EE-30FD-86C8-483289E15B3C> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications/Spotlight.app/Spotlight
       0x1094f8000 -        0x10955050f +dyld_sim (828.4) <C06A3B9E-9C65-32D9-9362-2107F24CA75E> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim
       0x1095a2000 -        0x1095d5ff4  com.apple.SpotlightUIInternal (1.0 - 1) <3BAFF27B-5845-39EC-9D46-347BC52B1323> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpotlightUIInternal.framework/SpotlightUIInternal
       ...

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 46258
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=656.0M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=656.0M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=12.5M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=12.5M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 
Stack                             8192K        2 
VM_ALLOCATE                        200K        1 
__DATA                            15.6M      555 
__DATA_CONST                      40.2M      440 
__DATA_DIRTY                        16K        3 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       234.5M      472 
__TEXT                           421.5M      452 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
dylib (reserved)                  2508K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
mapped file                       10.2M        1 
shared memory                        8K        2 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            789.3M     1932 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   786.8M     1932 

Model: MacBookPro15,4, BootROM 1037.147.4.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.16610.0.0,0), 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i5, 1,4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisGraphics645Item, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 645, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, SK Hynix, -
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, SK Hynix, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme, wl0: Feb 28 2020 15:26:30 version 16.20.192.27.3.6.77 FWID 01-f80dbb9b
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.6f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: Apple T2 Bus
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Touch Bar Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 51.1
```

Package.json

````
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^1.8.2",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.9",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.5.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "~0.62.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.8.2",
    "react-native-map-clustering": "^3.3.9",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the 8badf00d error message was triggered by an update to xCode or my Mac's OS. The app did start even though the message appeared so I just went along and have build a release APK for android without problems. I won't be able to test it for iPhone as of yet but would assume its somewhat the same.

Will post a short update after I have tested it for iPhone so I can confirm that the issue is with my Mac and not the actual app.